# Is the ObsHub OVSMU Source User(s) list really populating correctly? How can I disable it?

Tags: opshub

I have a locally deployed TFS server running 10.0.40219.339.

I want to migrate 3 distinct team projects from our local TFS installation to 3 distinct team projects in VSTS.

I am running OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility (free ed) version OVSMU-v2.2.2.001

In visual studio Team Services, I created a Team Project that is named identically to the team project that is in my locally deployed TFS server, using the Agile process template.

In OVSMU, I select "New Migration"

I selected the source endpoint as the locally deployed instance of TFS 2010.
I selected the destination endpoint as an instance of VSTS.
I selected the radio button labeled "I want to migrate version control data".
I selected from the "Select Team Projects" box the team project that I want to migrate.  (hypothetically called "Team Project 1")

When the User Mapping screen appears, it does not show the correct "Source Users".

If I click back, and navigate to a DIFFERENT team project (Hypothetically named "Team Project 2") on the same locally deployed TFS project collection, the list of source users is unchanged.

If I click Back, and navigate to a DIFFERENT team project (Hypothetically named "Team project 3") on the same locally deployed TFS project collection, the list of source users is unchanged.

If I close OSVMU, and start over, follow the same process, but instead of starting with Team Project 1, I start with Team Project 2, I get a somewhat different list of users than what I got when I started with Team Project 1.

In short, I feel that the population of the Source User(s) list is not functioning as intended.

1) It doesn't display the users that I expect... I don't even show up in the list of source users, and I'm clearly able to access the team project, as I have both changesets and the correct privileges to check in.

2) the users that it does show has a consistent list across all 3 of my team projects...  I think it's just caching the list and regenerates it the first time you access any team project, and reapplies that same source to subsequent project teams without refreshing the list from the server.

Is there a way that I can disable this filtering feature so I can see all of my TFS users in the source list?  The current filtering technique makes this tool not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. OVSMU only loads Project Users. i.e. Users who are either in the Project Team or member of any of the project's default/custom User Group. So, if you have users who are a part of any collection group but not explicitly in any project team/group, they are **not** loaded. 
   This behavior is inherit to overcome the burden of mapping those additional users who are not a part of the project being migrated. In case users are not being loaded at your end for a project, make sure there are users who are a part of any of the project's team/group.
2. The behavior of changing the project and coming back to user mapping screen to find no change is currently known and deliberate. You will have to explicitly press the 'refresh' button (in the button frame) on the User Mapping screen to reload users (based on whatever change you have done)