# OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility does not find any "Source Users" to map

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am trying to migrate from TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Team Services (source code only). 
Everything goes fine until I get to the user mapping screen. 
It has no issues finding the destination users, but it does not find any source users, so i cannot map them, and therefore cannot continue to the next step.

There are no errors.
I have tried three different projects.
I am using the free version: OVSMU-V2.5.0.001

EDIT- adding error from opshub.log:

04/26/2017 08:56:10,840 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1] (com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet) - Error while trying to install license VisualStudio.lic
com.opshub.license.exception.LicenseException: License with key 1258 is already installed
    at com.opshub.license.install.LicenseInstaller.checkDuplicateLicense(LicenseInstaller.java:127)
    at com.opshub.license.install.LicenseInstaller.installLicense(LicenseInstaller.java:72)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.registerLicFile(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:369)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.installLicenses(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:345)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.contextInitialized(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:951)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1819)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Are you the administrator of TFS? Are there errors in log fine? (C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs\)

Comment: Yes, I am the admin for TFS. I did find an error in the log files relating to licensing. updating the post shortly with that info. @starain-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there are users who are explicitly in corresponding team/group.

> OVSMU only loads Project Users. i.e. Users who are either in the
>   Project Team or member of any of the project's default/custom User
>   Group. So, if you have users who are a part of any collection group
>   but not explicitly in any project team/group, they are not loaded.
>   This behavior is inherit to overcome the burden of mapping those
>   additional users who are not a part of the project being migrated. In
>   case users are not being loaded at your end for a project, make sure
>   there are users who are a part of any of the project's team/group.

More information, you can refer to: [Is the ObsHub OVSMU Source User(s) list really populating correctly? How can I disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131053/is-the-obshub-ovsmu-source-users-list-really-populating-correctly-how-can-i-d)